# Espresso - How to click the 'PASTE' context menu option in an EditText using Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I can't manage to get **Espresso** to find the `EditText` context menu.

I've tried the following

```
onView(withText(containsString("PASTE")).perform(click())
```

Espresso test recorder gave me the following code, but that doesn't work either. It crashes with a `NoMatchingViewException` exception

```
onView(allOf(withContentDescription("Paste"), childAtPosition(childAtPosition(withClassName(`is`("android.widget.RelativeLayout")),1),0),isDisplayed())).perform(click())
```

How can I click the **Paste** context menu option in my `EditText` using Espresso?